# I want to create a dynamic dropdown in loop

Tags: php, loops, drop-down-menu, html-select

My requirement is to display CSV headers as the first element, then for each header, I want to map the element to elements appearing in drop-down. When first drop-down element is selected, it should dynamically populate second drop-down.

Example say my csv has the headers: first, second, third my first drop-down has values: 1, 2, 3 Then Based on 1: I should get second drop-down as a, b Then Based on 2: i should get second drop-down as i, j Then Based on 3: I should get second drop-down as p, q
i.e. First: (drop-down if 1 selected) (drop-down a, b) appears.
My problem is I am getting this done when I do not run this on loop. When I give a for loop for populating the csv header, automatically, the send drop-down does not appear.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have given, onchange function for second dropdown to appear.

Comment: Good for you, but if you show your code we can actually try and help, without it we are all just goin to move to the next question. Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) **We do not work from specs**